# Post ID route showing up in other components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-router

I am learning router and redux. I am trying to create a blog. Now the post ID route is showing up in other components like About and portfolio but not in home page because I have made it an exact path.

https://github.com/chiranjeebhub/router-redux

### Post.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Post extends Component {
  render() {
    const post = this.props.post ? (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.props.post.title}</h4>
        <p>{this.props.post.body}</p>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>
        <p>loading post ... </p>
      </div>
    );
    return <div>{post}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let id = ownProps.match.params.post_id;
  return {
    post: state.posts.find(post => post.id == id)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Post);
```

### My Routers:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import About from "./Components/About";
import Post from "./Components/post";
import Portfolio from "./Components/portfolio";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
          <Route path="/:post_id" component={Post} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### About.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>About Me</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

### Reducer

```
const initState = {
  posts: [
    { id: "1", title: "title1", body: "body1" },
    { id: "2", title: "title2", body: "body2" },
    { id: "3", title: "title3", body: "body3" },
    { id: "4", title: "title4", body: "body4" }
  ]
};

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  return state;
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Now when I load "About" component the "Loading Posts..." shows up from post.js

Comment: when you load `portfolio` same `"Loading Posts..."` shows up ?

Comment: Yes. It shows up in portfolio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having issue because the path

```
<Route path="/:post_id" component={Post} />
```

shows that a dynamic value is expected at the `post_id` placeholder. As `post_id` is just a placeholder using `about`, `portfolio`, `1`, etc as route parameters will satisfy the condition.

i.e

```
// All of them are valid
/about
/portfolio
/1
```

So `Post` component shows up along with other components.

Therefore you should wrap `Route` components with `Switch` Component. As `Switch` component only renders the first child that matches the path so `Post` component will not  show up when `/about` and `/portfolio` is used.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

 <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
        <Route path="/:post_id" component={Post} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```